# Excel 2013 + Bloomberg: Application.OnKey "^%" issue (CTRL+ALT+x accelerator)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, bloomberg

I've got an Excel spreadsheet which define these 2 accelerator keys

```
Application.OnKey "^{g}", "Mats_Menu.xls!DisplayGraph"
Application.OnKey "^%{g}", "Mats_Menu.xls!DisplayGraph"
```

- Excel 2010 without Bloomberg => accelerator keys are working fine
- Excel 2013 without Bloomberg => accelerator keys are working fine
- Excel 2010 on a Bloomberg terminal => accelerator keys are working fine
- Excel 2013 on a Bloomberg terminal => only the first accelerator key is working

After few tests, looks like `Application.OnKey "^%{.}"` doesn't work with Excel 2013 on a Bloomberg terminal.

Can you help me to fix this issue?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason is (assuming Excel 2013 was updated more recently than the 2010 version was) the newer Bloomberg "Office Tools" add-in for Excel overrides certain keyboard shortcuts with their own. You can access the Hot Key Manager from the Bloomberg tab on the Ribbon (top of Excel > Bloomberg > Options > Hot Key Manager) and try disabling whichever one conflicts with your shortcut assignment.

Not all versions of the Office Tools add-in have Hot Key manager, and I believe those versions which lack it wouldn't suffer the shortcut override, but to be sure you can just disable the add-in completely and then test.

Comment: I confirm, that was it! Thanks very much for your help!